# Is '-text' or 'text eol=lf' more suitable for *.sh files inside .gitattributes?

Tags: git, gitattributes

Quite often in my projects I commit `*.sh` files which are executed from within a `Dockerfile`.

This means that even Windows users need these files to be checked-out with LF line-endings, otherwise docker fails executing them.

For this I use `.gitattributes` but still not sure whether 
`-text` or `text eol=lf` is the best practice.

The same question applies for `*.bat` files (e.g. linux-users need to execute them on a Windows VM): `-text` vs `text eol=crlf`.

Comment: The Git repository for Git uses `*.sh whitespace=indent,trail,space eol=lf`: no files are marked `text` or `-text` at all. Much of this is a matter of taste but if that's good enough for the people who maintain Git... :-)

Comment: On the other hand Git docs have `text` in the [sample](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_end_of_line_conversion).